# Override "private" method in java

Tags: java

There something ambiguous about this idea and I need some clarifications.

My problem is when using this code:

```
public class B {

    private void don() {
        System.out.println("hoho private");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B t = new A();
        t.don();
    }
}

class A extends B {
    public void don() {
        System.out.println("hoho public");
    }
}
```

The output is `hoho private`.

Is this because the main function is in the same class as the method `don`, or because of overriding?

I have read this idea in a book, and when I put the `main` function in another class I get a compiler error.

Comment: Some good reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000137/overriding-private-methods-in-java

Comment: you are hiding and not overriding.

Comment: In addition to not be visible outside the type (and perhaps more relevant to the question here), private methods are *not polymorphic* - only the method defined on the type of the expression will ever be invoked; no dynamic dispatch occurs. In the shown example, *the `t` expression is of type `B`* and thus `t.don()` will *always* be invoking B's `don`. The *run-time type `A` is irrelevant* and no 'overriding' of such a private method is allowed.

Comment: then how [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976446/can-a-private-method-in-super-class-be-overridden-in-the-sub-class) works even the subclass object is assigned to subclass reference it still calls parent class private method

Comment: More than the accepted answer, the comment from @user2864740 solves the real ambiguous behaviour.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot override a `private` method. It isn't visible if you cast `A` to `B`. You **can** override a `protected` method, but that isn't what you're doing here (and yes, here if you move your `main` to `A` then you would get the other method. I would recommend the `@Override` annotation when you intend to override,

```
class A extends B {
    @Override
    public void don() { // <-- will not compile if don is private in B.
        System.out.println("hoho public");
    }
}
```

> In this case why didn't compiler provide an error for using `t.don()` which is `private`?

[The Java Tutorials: Predefined Annotation Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html) says (in part)

> While it is not required to use this annotation when overriding a method, it helps to prevent errors. If a method marked with `@Override` fails to correctly override a method in one of its superclasses, the compiler generates an error.

Comment: Thank you Elliott, but how the main function can use t.don() while it is a private method inside the class B

Comment: @basel Because it is **in** class `B`. Every function **in** class `B` can access the private methods in class `B`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch But using `@Override` should give a compile-time error, right? We are trying to override a `private` method. (It is a genuine question and I am not trying to correct you :))

Comment: @Kaushik `private` methods are not inherited, so you **can't** override them. Correct. Using the annotation when you intend to `Override` will cause a compilation error when you do not in fact `Override` a method. Which was entirely my point.

Answer (score 7):

> is this because the main function is in the same class as the method "don"

No, it's because `A`'s `don()` is unrelated to `B`'s `don()` method, in spite of having the same name and argument list. `private` methods are hidden inside their class. They cannot be invoked directly by outside callers, such as `main` method in your case, because they are encapsulated inside the class. They do not participate in method overrides.

Comment: in this case then why the compiler didnt give compile error for using t.don() which is private??

Comment: Because it is valid in the Java language

Answer (score 6):

No, a private method cannot be overridden since it is not visible from any other class. You have declared a new method for your subclass that has no relation to the superclass method. One way to look at it is to ask yourself whether it would be legal to write super.func() in the Derived class.

Comment: Private methods **can** be visible from other classes in very specific scenarios. It is erroneous to convolute visibility with inheritance because they don't always match up.

Comment: @Kröw : Please update your knowledge, you can not call or override the private method directly from outside class, indirectly you can call it from public method declared in the same class and that public method  can be called from the outside, but that's still indirectly, indirectly everything is possible! ..........be specific!

Comment: Private methods *can* be called directly from a nested class.

Answer (score 4):

You can't *override* a private method, but you can introduce one in a derived class without a problem. The derive class can not access the private method on the ancestor.

Since *t* is a on object of type **B**, calling don() method will invoque the method defined at B. It doesn't even know that there is a method named also don() at class **A**

Answer (score 4):

private members aren't visible to any other classes, even children

You can't override a private method, but then again, you can't call it either. You can create an identical method with the same name in the child however.

```
public class A
{
    private int calculate() {return 1;}
    public void visibleMethod()
    {
        System.out.println(calculate());
    };
}

public class B extends A
{
    private int calculate() {return 2;}
    public void visibleMethod()
    {
        System.out.println(calculate());
    };
}
```

If you call A.visibleMethod() it prints out 1.

If you call B.visibleMethod() it prints 2.

If you don't implement the private calculate() method in B, it won't compile because the public method that calls it can't see the private method in A.

Comment: But can I override `calculate` in B without having to re-implement `visibleMethod`?